# All compilers: disable warnings for some headers

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have a cross-platform project. It's compiled using different compilers (gcc, clang, msvc++).

For now, the only problem with warnings I have is due to Boost headers. Gcc generates a bunch of them for my project being compiled for Android platform.

What I would like to do is to disable all warnings generation for Boost headers (because it's a useless stuff for me).

So, I've created the following two files:

**compiler_warnings_pop.h**

```
//WARNING: no #pragma once here
#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__GNUG__)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

**compiler_warnings_push.h**

```
//WARNING: no #pragma once here
#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__GNUG__)
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#pragma warning(push)
#endif
```

Now I need a code that can temporarily disable all the warnings for any compiler. Is there one? So I could use the following code:

```
#include <compiler_warnings_push.h>
#include <compiler_warnings_disable.h>
#include <boost/...>
#include <compiler_warnings_pop.h>
```

Comment: gcc has pragmas that disable individual warnings. Each warning message indicates the message's corresponding option, and this is what you stick into the pragma: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: My project has "QuietBoost/Spirit.h" (for example), which wraps the Boost Spirit.hpp with `#pragma` to disable the noisy cricket warnings.  We only wrap the Boost ones we use.  We only squelch the warnings for the compilers we use.  There isn't a standard way to do so; each is on a compiler-by-compiler basis.

Comment: With templates, it might not always "works" as some warnings might be generated at the instantiation point. Not sure if it is still a problem with recent compilers.